# How to check if the network entry in /proc/net exists in C?

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to write a C program to iterate through `/proc/net` and obtain the specified network protocols in the `net` array.

The code is currently able to iterate through `/proc/net`. However, after adding the `if` statement to print if the current entry matches the name in the `net` array, nothing prints. Why is this the case?

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define NETWORK_PROTOCOLS 8

const char* net[] = {"tcp", "tcp6", "udp", "udp6", "udplite", "udplite6", "icmp", "icmp6"};

int main(void)
{
    DIR *d;
    struct dirent *dir;
    d = opendir("/proc/net");
    if (d)
    {
        while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
        {
            for (int i=0; i < NETWORK_PROTOCOLS; i++) 
            {
              if (dir->d_name == net[i])
                   printf("%s\n\n", dir->d_name);
            }
        }
        closedir(d);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: BTW: Take the [tour] and read [ask]. Further, you should always extract a [mcve] first, it might have given you the hint that this has nothing to do with Linux API or network protocols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Read [*Modern C*](http://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) and [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/).

Strings should be compared with [strcmp(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html) since `==` compare addresses. So replace your `if` statement with

```
  if (!strcmp(dir->d_name, net[i])))
     printf("%s\n", dir->dirname);
```

Read also documentation of [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) and later some [draft C standard](https://files.lhmouse.com/standards/ISO%20C%20N2176.pdf). You want to compile your code with warnings and [DWARF](http://www.dwarfstd.org/doc/DWARF5.pdf) debug information [as](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` and then use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger.

You could also use [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/) or the [Clang static source code](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) analyzer on your C source code (or, in February 2021, [bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/) funded by [CHARIOT](https://www.chariotproject.eu/) and [DECODER](https://www.decoder-project.eu/) projects)

See also [glob(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html), [glob(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html), [fnmatch(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fnmatch.3.html), [stat(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html), [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), [nftw(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html), [errno(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html), [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), [elf(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html), [gcc(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcc.1.html), [ld(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html). Use [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to understand the behavior of your [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable), or of existing [processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)).

#### Take inspiration from *existing* [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html) source code, such as [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) and [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/),  etc....

If permitted, you might [learn C++](https://www.stroustrup.com/programming.html) then use libraries like [POCO](https://pocoproject.org/) or [Qt](https://qt.io/), and study for inspiration the source code of [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), or of [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/), or of [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/), or of [fish](https://fishshell.com/).

You will learn a lot by *contributing* to some open source project on [github](https://github.com/) or [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/) or elsewhere.

Read also some [textbook on operating systems](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/).